# How to fix error "npm ERR! missing script: start"

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-27T18_02_39_6
60Z-debug.log
```

This is what I am doing -
In my package.json I have written the following code:

```
{
"name":"javaScript-blockchain",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "description":"",
    "main":"index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test":"echo \"Error:no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start":"node dev/api.js"
    }
    "author":"Samrat Roy Chowdhuri",
    "license":"ISC",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":"^4.16.3",
        "nodemon":"^1.17.3",
        "sha256":"^0.2.0"
    }
}
```

Then in my Node prompt I run npm start and get the above error

In the log the following is mentioned:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
5 verbose cwd E:\programs\blockchain
6 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v10.15.3
9 verbose npm  v6.4.1
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: Did you try `npm run start`?

Comment: Did you run `npm start` in the same folder as the `package.json`?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb yes, in the same directory

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes tried that, same result

Comment: do you try to run this on an external harddrive?

Comment: @messerbill no, i do not own one! :(

Comment: are you sure that you tried `npm run start` and / or `npm start` while you have been in the same directory as that `package.json` file?

Comment: what happens if you try to install something and save it like `npm install --save react` just for a test?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. you just need a comma after the script curly bracket which is just after the start script

```js
{
"name":"javaScript-blockchain",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "description":"",
    "main":"index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test":"echo \"Error:no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start":"node dev/api.js"
    },
    "author":"Samrat Roy Chowdhuri",
    "license":"ISC",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":"^4.16.3",
        "nodemon":"^1.17.3",
        "sha256":"^0.2.0"
    }
}
```